# How to set the environment variabile using java

Tags: 14.04, java, environment-variables

I am trying to set an environment variable using a java code. When i run this java code from the bash, I want to echo the environment variable that i set in the java program. How can this be done

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking of something like this:

```
$ java Foo
$ echo ${var_set_by_foo}
```

This *cannot* be done. A process cannot affect another's environment, and a Java program is perforce run as a separate process from your shell.